# How to pass SqlDbType.udt to stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, user-defined-types

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure using ADO.NET. The stored procedure has  few parameters of UDT type. I'm using below code to call the stored proc and passing parameter but it looks like the value being passed to proc is not the one that I'm passing but default value of that type.

```
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procName, _conn))
        {
            if (input != null)
            {
                foreach (Parameter inputPair in input)
                {
                    SqlParameter sp = new SqlParameter("@" + inputPair.Name, inputPair.Type);
                    sp.Value = inputPair.Value;
                    sp.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputPair.UdtTypeName))
                    {
                        sp.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Udt;
                        sp.UdtTypeName = inputPair.UdtTypeName;
                    }

                    if (0 != inputPair.Size)
                    {
                        sp.Size = inputPair.Size;
                    }
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(sp);
                }
            }
```

Any pointer is much appreciated .

Comment: What is inputPair.Type? Maybe you should pass SqlDbType.Udt to the SqlParameter constructor like in Microsoft's Msdn example ...

Comment: inputPair is a custom class which contains sql parameter name, type, value etc.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?